# Unable to execute shell script through php shell_exec

Tags: php, shell

I have a binary file whose path is mentioned in the .bashrc file, I am able to execute it through command line. I copied the command to run the binary file into a bash(test.sh) file. 
I am trying to execute this test.sh file through Php using the command

```
<php
    shell_exec("test.sh")
?>
```

This says that command not found.

Comment: You are calling a PHP script via Ajax, correct?

Comment: no, using shell_exec("test.sh")

Comment: It may be an issue with path, does executing the command in shell script from same working directory from where you run the script works?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your webserver configuration forbid execution of system commands.
Check your php.ini "disable_functions" section. If you see there something like below, this is the reason.

```
disable_functions=exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
```

> I'm trying to execute docker command in that runApp.sh file

Remember, you script executes INSIDE docker container. It doesn't have access to the mother system.
If you want to execute docker commands inside docker container, your need [docker in docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker)

Comment: The OP appears to be attempting to run Docker commands on the host via a shell script, so they do not need Docker in Docker.